# how to use Multi threading in squeak smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

i would like to know how to work with Threads in squeak smalltlak

```
b1 := Ball new.
b2 := Ball new.
```

this 2 next objects should run in different Threads together(Multi threading).
how can i do it ?

```
"Thread 1"
    b1  start:210 at:210.    "start is the name of the method"

"Thread 2"        
    b2  start:310 at:210.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the Squeak VM only offers green threads, i.e. the VM runs in a single process and threads are *simulated* inside this single process.

To use threads (simply called *processes* in Squeak) you usually send the message `#fork` or `#forkAt:` to a block:

```
[ b1 start: 210 at: 210 ] fork.
[ b1 start: 210 at: 210 ] forkAt: Processor userBackgroundPriority.
```

That's all there is to it really, unless you need facilities for inter process communication. Then you can use a `Mutex` for critical sections (only one process can be in this section at a time) or a `Semaphore` for controlling access to a shared resource:

```
"before critical section"
self mutex critical: [ "critical section" ].
"after critical section"

"access shared resource"
self semaphore wait.
"do stuff..."
"release shared resource"
self semaphore signal.
```

The methods `#semaphore` and `#mutex` are simply accessors to variables. These variables should **not** be initialised lazily but **before** multiple processes may call the methods. That usually means you'll initialise them in the `#initialize` method:

```
initialize
  semaphore := Semaphore new.
  mutex := Mutex new.
```

The reason for this is that you can not guarantee that a process will not be suspended in the `#ifNil:` block. This could result in two processes using two different mutexes / semaphores.

If you need more information, you should take a look at the [Deep into Pharo](http://pharo.org/documentation) book and maybe read the original Smalltalk books by Adele Goldberg (available at your favourite online book store).

Comment: i get an error for backgroundPriority what could be the reason ? he is offering :
BackgroundProcess  Or  UserBackgroundPriority

Comment: Yes, sorry. That should be `#userBackgroundPriority`. Fixed in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

And you should of course be careful about the interactions between your  [threads and the UI](http://osdir.com/ml/lang.smalltalk.squeak.general/2004-12/msg01057.html).

You might not need threads, you can also use stepping in Morphic.